# Showing that every plane curve with constant curvature is a circle by solving the Frenet differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I recently saw the following example that shows that plane curves with constant curvature are circles:

Let $\kappa \neq 0$ be constant and $s \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary, then by the Frenet Matrix-equation we get

$E(s)=exp \biggl(s \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\kappa \\ 
-\kappa & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\biggr)=\begin{pmatrix}
cos(\kappa s) & sin(\kappa s) \\ 
-sin(\kappa s) & cos(\kappa s) 
\end{pmatrix}
$

Now my question is regarding how to get to that result.

I know that the Frenet Matrix Equation (for plane curves) is
$\begin{pmatrix}
e_{11}'(s) & e_{12}'(s) \\ 
e_{21}'(s) & e_{22}'(s) 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\kappa \\ 
-\kappa & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
e_{11}(s) & e_{12}(s) \\ 
e_{21}(s) & e_{22}(s)
\end{pmatrix}$

Also by googling I now know that the matrix exponential for some $n \times n$ matrix $A$ as
$e^{A}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!}$.

I do know that for some function $f$, the equation
$f'(x)=c f(x)$ has the solution, $C_1 e^{cx}$, but I don't understand the "matrix version".

I am not very familiar with differential equations.

Comment: Are you sure the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\kappa \\ 
-\kappa & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get by without looking at matrix exponentials. The equations are

$$T'(s) = \kappa N(s) \quad\mbox{and}\quad N'(s) = -\kappa T(s),$$right? They imply that $T''(s) = \kappa (-\kappa T(s))$, and thus $T''(s) + \kappa^2 T(s) = 0$.

You should know that in the scalar case, the solution of $y''(s) + \kappa^2 y(s) = 0$ is given by $y(s) = c_1 \cos(\kappa s) + c_2 \sin(\kappa s)$, with $c_1,c_2\in \Bbb R$. Applying the scalar version componentwise, we see that solving the vector version amounts to replacing the numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ with vectors $v_1,v_2 \in \Bbb R^2$. Hence

$$T(s) = \cos(\kappa s) v_1 + \sin(\kappa s)v_2,\qquad\mbox{with } v_1,v_2\in \Bbb R^2.$$

We also know that $T(0) = v_1$ and $N(0) = v_2$ are orthonormal. But $T(s) = \alpha'(s)$, so we may integrate the above and obtain $$\alpha(s) = \frac{1}{\kappa} \sin(\kappa s)v_1 - \frac{1}{\kappa}\cos(\kappa s) v_2 + p,$$where $p\in \Bbb R^2$ is a last constant of integration. There you go, a circle of radius $1/|\kappa|$ centered at $p$...